# How to add a NPM package correctly in the plunker?

Tags: angular, npm, plunker

I got an [error](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll/issues/28#issuecomment-226467954) when using **angular2-infinite-scroll**. I want to reproduce it in a plunkr.

I tried to use [npmcdn](https://npmcdn.com/), so I add this line in the **index.html** file:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2-infinite-scroll@0.1.2"></script>
```

But I got the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ojma6uqmrkWZ19uGptjm).

How can I add a NPM package correctly in the plunker?

Comment: Add it to the `map` object in your `config.js` file and possibly also in the `packages` object, if the package doesn't have a `index.js`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add it to the `map` object in your `config.js` file and possibly also in the `packages` object, if the package doesn't have a `index.js`.

```json
map: {
    [...],
    'angular2-infinite-scroll': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-infinite-scroll@0.1.2'
},
packages: {
    [...],
    'angular2-infinite-scroll': {
        main: 'angular2-infinite-scroll.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
},
```

---

> working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uof65imnVnMooMlBksoe?p=preview)

Comment: thanks! but I think the Plunker link u gave to me is wrong.. Or maybe u didn't save

Comment: Uh, forgot to save :)

Comment: Hmm, angular2-infinite-scroll 0.1.2 should work properly.. Because the error I met is only in 0.1.3. Maybe still something wrong in the plunker?

Comment: Oh, I found the error in your plunker. After removing duplicated `directives: []` in the **app.ts**, the error is gone!

Comment: I leave the working version with `onScroll` function here: https://plnkr.co/edit/uof65imnVnMooMlBksoe?p=preview

Comment: `the error in your plunker` - I just fixed your imports, not your actual code - haha